# How to get the count of Message in a service bus Using Logic App?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I have a service Bus. Some time Number of Messages in the Subscription under Topic gets jammed.

So i want to use a Logic app to count the number of message stuck in the Service Bus in every interval & send the alert.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: any help can i get here?

Comment: Did you find the answer below helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Azure Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-metrics-azure-monitor) to measure the number of items in the bus, and [Azure Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/alert-metric) to notify you.

Comment: Nope, already tried this process. Alert also in place, but i am waiting for the alert from last 5 days. As its in preview mode, so we can't even complain it to azure care.